# Поздапрос внутри подзапроса внутри подзапроса

Tags: sql, oracle

Нужно в подзапросе внутри подзапроса внутри подзапроса кореллироваться со значением поля сАмой внешней таблицы. Запрос такой:

```
select  (
select CATEG from 
(select CATEG  from SHIFTS where TABNOM = STATE.TABNOM  order by TABNOM, DATEPR desc)
where ROWNUM = 1
)
from STATE
```

Тут пытаюсь получить категорию (CATEG) из самой последней по дате (DATEPR) записи для данного 
табельного номера (TABNOM) сотрудника из таблицы перемещений (SHIFTS), для всех записей из штатного расписания (STATE).

Но получаю ошибку:

*Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00904: "STATE"."TABNOM": недопустимый идентификатор*

Нужно сделать без join-ов, только подзапросами, так как весь запрос частично формируется приложением, на которое повлиять нельзя.

Comment: помимо 2х предложенных решений для Oracle 12c можно использовать  `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY`. Для любых версий оракла может оказаться удобным сделать функцию (create function ...) и вообще забыть о подзапросе, сам запрос в итоге будет вроде `select getLastCategory(tabnom) from state`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно уменьшить уровень вложенности с помощью такой хитрой конструкции:

```
select (select max(categ) keep (dense_rank first order by datepr desc) categ
          from shifts
         where tabnom = state.tabnom)
  from state
```

Выражение `max(categ) keep (dense_rank first order by datepr desc)` означает "отсортировать таблицу по убыванию поля `datepr`, взять строки минимальным `dense_rank` (то есть последнее значение даты), из них взять максимальное значение поля `categ`".

Comment: гм, интересно вы решили что максимальная категория станет последней - как так? )) на Oracle 2 вложенных подзапроса мне кажется норм, а в норм базах один вложенный

Comment: @EugeneBartosh Dmitry не ошибся, при использовании фразы KEEP сама агрегатная функция не имеет значения, можно написать хоть AVG, внутрь функции попадет только 1 значение, отобранное в порядке сортировки указанной для KEEP. А 2 вложенных запроса, конечно не проблема, пока не надо ссылаться из самого внутреннего в самый внешний

Comment: @EugeneBartosh Я не решил, я просто предложил. Если вам или автору вопроса нравится другая агрегатная функция - используйте ее. Тут главная проблема в том, что в этой конструкции использовать агрегатную функцию обязательно.

Comment: Для этого случая можно самописную функцию `noagr` использовать,  чтобы не смущала.

Answer (score 0):

Без данных сложно, но попробуй так:

```
select (
    select distinct First_Value(h.Categ) over (partition by h.Tabnom order by h.Datepr desc)
    from SHIFTS h
    where h.TabNom = s.Tabnom)
from State s
```

Answer (score 0):

Вспомнилось из Горячие Головы 2 - "сейчас собираем команду чтобы спасти тех, кто отправился спасать тех, чтобы выручить тех, которые выступили помочь тем, кого захватили враги" :)

Решение проблемы в том, чтобы использовать синонимы, в частности обязательно для подзапросов в FROM, заодно и для полей советую использовать, также везде к полям обращаться советую только через TABLE.FIELD - это экономит много времени, когда запросы начинают усложняться, и особенно когда присутствуют подзапросы. Я не знаю какое поле из какой таблицы у вас, так что расставьте сами. 
Также в вашем случае необходимо применение LIMIT 1, благодаря этому сможете избавиться от второго подзапроса и зделать запрос совместимым с SQL ANSI. TABNOM в order by - нонсенс, это как если бы вы предложили 100 Ивановым перечистить себя в алфавитном порядке по фамилии. 
В окончательном виде:

```
 select 
   (select SHIFTS.CATEG 
       from SHIFTS where SHIFTS.TABNOM = STATE.TABNOM  
       order by SHIFTS.DATEPR desc 
       LIMIT 1
   ) as CATEG 
 from STATE
```

P.S. Ну раз Oracle то тада так, уже забыл про этого мостра, со временем перестал его отличать от PostgreSQL  :-)

```
select 
  ( select TAB1.CATEG as CAT1 from 
    ( select SHIFTS.CATEG as CAT2 from SHIFTS 
       where SHIFTS.TABNOM = STATE.TABNOM  
       order by SHIFTS.DATEPR desc) as TAB1
      where ROWNUM = 1
   ) as CATEG
from STATE
```

Comment: Это Oracle. В нем нет LIMIT (как раз условие ROWNUM=1 применяется вместо него).

Comment: И к сожалению ANSI совместимые запросы не совместимы с Oracle, в нем до 9 версии даже слова JOIN не было ... все решалось по другому. перед тем как писать ответ по конкретной БД всегда проверяйте а действительно ли написанное совместимо

Comment: @Mike ага, точно, вспомнил )) написал и для Oracle

Comment: Ваше второе решение то же не будет работать. Oracle не позволяет обращаться из коррелированного подзапроса к полям таблицы более чем на 1 уровень вложенности вверх. собственно проблема ТС заключается именно в этом. возможны варианты только с одним уровнем вложенности

Comment: ужасы, как хорошо что я всё это уже забыл :-))) сорри тогда за конфузии, ну не ораклист я, поэтому не шмагла ))

Comment: @Mike и в ANSI оказывается LIMIT тоже нет, это я уже так привык... Дауш... отличная возможность поучиться - когда попробуешь поучить кого-то еще...

Comment: Ну я например как раз с ораклом много работал, только в основном на старых версиях. Все остальные СУБД и новые возможности Oracle изучил, отвечая тут :)